# Rate of change - derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The picture below shows a conical container , initially full , of height $12cm$ and radius $4cm$ . Water is being pumped out of the container through an opening at the base of the container at a constant rate of $8cm^3/s& .

After $t$ seconds , the depth of the water is $hcm$.

Given that the volume of the water in the container ,

$Vcm^3$ at time $t$ seconds is given by

$V= 64\left(\pi\right) - \frac{\left(\pi\right)}{27} (12-h)^3 $ ,

Find the rate of change of the depth when the volume of water in the container is $37\left(\pi\right) cm^3$
[image]

My workings and doubts -

$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dh} X \frac{dh}{dt} $

My only doubt is on $ \frac{dv}{dh} $

Why must I only differentiate - $\frac{\left(\pi\right)}{27} (12-h)^3 $ and not the entire thing ?

Thanks

Comment: There is a wildly missplaced $ somewhere here

Comment: What do u mean from "entire thing"?.....